# c++ - is there a way to have "inline" structs (similar to inline namespaces)

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct, inline, standard-layout

If I have two structs:

```
struct Base {
    int a;
};

struct Derived : Base {
    int b;
};
```

then with an instance `Derived d`, I can directly access `a` and `b` as `d.a` and `d.b`.

However with this setup, `Derived` isn't a standard layout type.

If I wanted to make it standard layout, I could do something like:

```
struct Derived {
    Base base;
    int b;
};
```

but then to access `a` I'd have to use `d.base.a` instead of `d.a` as before.

Can I can declare the `Derived` struct in a way that lets me access `a` and `b` as in the first example, while keeping it a standard layout type?

Comment: With  getters, you might have same interface.